# Where do I default a home page in my asp.net website app?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, webforms-routing

I have a website that uses webforms routing.

At the moment the home page route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("home", "", "~/public/Home.aspx");
```

However, I'm considering changing it for the purpose of SEO. I guess I have 2 related questions to ask:

Will mysite.com/keyword be better for SEO than simply mysite.com? In other words does Google take into account phrases after the domain name?

If I change the route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("home", "mykeyword", "~/public/Home.aspx");
```

How can I ensure that anyone who types in www.mysite.com is redirected to www.mysite.com/mykeyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that Google [doesn't like redirection on a home page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2721217) so you would be best off just using mysite.com and optimise the content on that page for your keyword (see the rest of Google's Webmaster Guidelines on best practice for this).

You can also create another page which would be mysite.com/keyword which would be more targeted for that specific keyword but lower in importance on Google as it isn't the home page so I would just stick with your current routing!